# chmod files only in all subdirectories

Tags: chmod

Please someone assist me with chmod, I have the following file structure

```
-dir1
--file1
--file2
--dir1a
---file1a1
---file1a2
--dir1b
---file1b1
---file1b2
```

How do I *chmod 655* to all files under dir1 and all subdir?
So all files will have 655 permission and all dir will remain as they were.

Thank you

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Better to use

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 655 -- {} +
```

The other proposed solution from @sagarchalise will not work if filenames contain spaces or start with a dash.

Comment: Relatedly, to chmod all directories you can use `find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +` to change all directories to 755.

Comment: What is the + for?

Comment: @Brettski: the `+` sign is expanded by `find` to the list of the file paths (or part of it, if too long).

Comment: What is the -- for?

Comment: The `--` indicates the end of command line options.  This prevents a file starting with a hyphen from being interpreted as a command line option as it would come after the `--`.

Answer (score 11):

I think going inside `dir1` and

`find . -type f | xargs chmod 655`

will do the trick.

Or this version, which supports file names with spaces:

`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 655`

Comment: this works too but i've got some warning with "No such file or directory"

Comment: @manetic: it depends, as said in my answer, on filenames containing spaces.

Comment: For completeness,  changing it  to  find .  -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 655 would fix the space issue I believe, although @enzotib's answer is more concise

Comment: what matt freake said